# Font not embedding on website

Tags: html, css, fonts

I know this is the most basic of issues but I can't figure out why my font isn't embedding.

CSS:

```
@font-face
{
font-family:"Moon_Flower";
src: url("assets/fonts/Moon_Flower.ttf") format ("truetype");

}


 html {
         font-family:Moon_Flower;
          background-image:url(../images/background.jpg);
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
          font-size: 18pt;
}
```

Can someone point out to me what I'm doing wrong here? I've checked multiple times and the string should work, it's the same I've used for images only with the "fonts" folder in place of the "images" folder. I tried with a different font also and it didn't work until I had installed it on the laptop.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You want to include multiple font source files to support different browsers.  Additionally, are you confident that your font file(s) are where you have linked to? Note on types: *TTF* - Works in most browsers except IE and iPhone, 
*EOT* - IE only,
*WOFF* - Compressed, emerging standard.
*SVG* - iPhone/iPad.

Comment: Note: Internet Explorer 8 and earlier, do not support the @font-face rule.

Comment: Try the generator over at Font Squirrel... http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot to mention I'm using the latest version of chrome. And yes, my font is definitely a .ttf. I've been Googling extensively but keep just coming across the same as what I have specified.

Comment: @omegaiori `font-face` works just fine in Internet Explorer 8 with the following: `url('xxx.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')`.

Comment: Insufficient information. There is no way even to access the actual font files referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try linking to the online ttf file. I found this one - **http://www.dafont.com/moon-flower.font**

Give this a try. Just make sure you're correctly linking to your files. Drop it into your CSS file.

**<kbd>[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/j88Nm/)</kbd>**

`@font-face {
        font-family: "Moon Flower";
        src: url('Moon-Flower.eot');
        src: url('Moon-Flower.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('Moon-Flower.svg#Moon Flower') format('svg'),
        url('Moon-Flower.woff') format('woff'),
        url('Moon-Flower.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
    body{
    font-family: "Moon Flower";
    direction: ltr;
    }`

Comment: I just tried that now. I changed the code to: 
src: url("http://www.dafont.com/moon-flower.font") format ("truetype"); It still doesn't seem to work in any browser

Comment: Would that the fact that this website hasn't gone online yet have anything to do with this? I'm clutching at straws here

Comment: No. Not if you're pulling from a url.

Comment: Can you post everything in a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Sure thing: http://jsfiddle.net/9RXY4/

Comment: I created the @font-face file for your here. Download from my server - http://webfro.gs/demo/fonts/Moon-Flower.zip

Comment: I added a JS Fiddle for you, but don't use my server links as permanent... I'll be deleting them in a few days.

Comment: Thanks! It works and I've got it working on my site with it's own directories. Not fully sure what the problem is but it's sorted. You can remove them from your server now and thanks again